# restricting visibility except through disabling the "Grant access via role hierarchy"

Tags: visibility, record-access-level

Need help to know, if there is any way to restrict the record level visibility for users above in hierarchy except through disabling the "Grant access via role hierarchy" on Object sharing setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. Sharing settings are additive, so there's no additional permissions you could set that would reduce visibility to some records without restricting access to all records.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation